# Eclipse project files compatibility with previous versions of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I need to save Eclipse CDT project files (`.project` and `.cproject`) in the source control repository. I also need to be able to support new versions of Eclipse once they are available, leaving the old version available for others to use before they update too.

How should I name the project directory to best reflect the Eclipse version that can open the saved project files? Current project files have been created with Eclipse Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3).

Example directory names I am thinking about:

```
/prj/eclipse
/prj/eclipse-4
/prj/eclipse-4.7
/prj/eclipse-4.7.3
```

I think the main question here is at what point does the Eclipse break backward compatibility with regards to project files?

Comment: The format of `.project` files has not changed in a very long time (if ever). No idea about .cproject

Comment: As long as no new features are used, it should be backward compatible. E. g. [a Meson project requires CDT 9.5](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn95#Build) (Eclipse Photon) or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDT doesn't make any guarantees about the stability of the `.cproject` format, so any CDT release could break backwards compatibility of project files.

In practice, I think the only major breakage recently has been in Eclipse Photon (4.8) due to the introduction of the new Core Build system. I believe things have been pretty stable for a while before that, though I can't be sure as this isn't really tracked anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Seems a bit strange that this changes aren't tracked anywhere. Are you sure?

Comment: @Danijel Well I mean I suppose you could look at the version control history of the code that reads/writes the `.cproject` format and reason about it based on that. But beyond that, no - I don't think it's strange that backwards-incompatible changes are not being tracked, if CDT doesn't provide compatibility guarantees about this format.